# Como dar um refresh no context? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu estou começando a desenvolver em ASP.NET e tenho sempre um pequeno problema.

Quando eu preciso gerar um contexto (Aquela classe que vai fazer a referência com o banco), exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu faço o seguinte procedimento: `Botão direito em cima do projeto -> Add -> new item -> data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model` depois disso eu dou o nome da classe conecto com o banco e gero todas as entidades baseadas no meu banco...

Quando eu mudo ou acrescendo qualquer campo no meu banco, toda vez eu tenho que deletar essa classe e cria-la novamente, eu gostaria de saber se há uma maneira de dar um `refresh`, e ela atualizar com os novos campos que estão no banco?

Se alguém saber essa solução, por favor compartilhe comigo, porque será de grande ajuda e de grande produtividade, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

Em seu caso, estás utilizando o *Database First*, que consiste em gerar o modelo de acordo com as tabelas em seu banco de dados.

Você pode atualizar seu **.edmx** normalmente, basta seguir esses passos:

1. Clique com o botão direito em seu arquivo **.edmx** e vá em **Update Model from Database.**;
2. Basta seguir os passos normais e pronto, mas vale lembrar que algumas coisas podem não atualizar, isso devido a N fatores.

A Microsoft explica isso [neste artigo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716697(v=vs.100).aspx) e [neste outro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc716705(v=vs.100).aspx).